# What are the causes of different memory issues in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, memory

Generally, I have seen 3 types of memory errors in Spark as follows,

```
1. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

2. Error: ExecutorLostFailure Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding limits. 9.1GB of 8GB physical memory used limits. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead

3. Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 4.5GB of 3GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

What are the main causes of these different types of errors? How the default number of RDDs, executor cores, executor instance, executor.memory, and executor.memoryOverhead are related to these errors.

In the memory management diagram of spark, what exactly is virtual memory?

I have spark job which runs perfectly fine with

```
("spark.driver.memory", "8g"),
("spark.executor.memory", "8g), 
("spark.executor.cores", 4), 
("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 500)
```

But when I increase default number of partitions to 1000, I get virtual memory issue as,

```
with
("spark.driver.memory", "8g"),
("spark.executor.memory", "8g), 
("spark.executor.cores", 4), 
("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1000)

The container is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 4.5 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container
```

Again when I increase my executor.memory to 12g with number of par, I get virtual memory issue as,

```
with
("spark.driver.memory", "8g"),
("spark.executor.memory", "12g), 
("spark.executor.cores", 4), 
("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1000)

The container is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 4.5 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container
```

I have dynamic allocation enabled and a hard limit on total memory usage i.e., 300GB, so my number of containers/executors changes automatically as I change my executor memory.

What actually is happening in the spark stack here and how can I optimize my resources?

Comment: The _Current usage: 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB_ with executor memory=12g doesnt look right. Could it be the driver container that's being killed?

Comment: Updated driver memory as well. This 1.5GB is somehow confusing to me as well. But this is what logs look like.

Comment: What I observe is 1000 RDD partitions are too much for my job. But what is reason for this?

Comment: Likely, having more partitions leads to extra overhead in using `spark.memory.fraction`. But I would rather focus on why your containers are running with 1.5GB memory. How do you submit your application?

Comment: I submit my spark job using the aforementioned configurations. I print all these configurations when the spark applications start and that print output is what I posted above.

Comment: I mean do you use cmd line/`spark-submit` or smth else?

Comment: Yes, command line spark submit. And cluster mode.